# Is it possible to run Axum on a single thread?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I know that Axum is built on top of Tokio and Tokio has a multi-threaded scheduler and current-threaded scheduler.

Is it possible to set the runtime to make it serve the requests in single thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since axum is just spawned in a tokio runtime with the `#[tokio::main]` macro or a system you setup. The futures are handled the way you configured the runtime.

Just do this if you're using the macro:

```rs
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    // Axum code here...
}
```

Here's the docs for more information for the macro: https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.3/tokio/attr.main.html#current-thread-runtime

And here's the non sugared way to setup a tokio runtime: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.new_current_thread